# STM32L1xx HAL_GPIO_Init Problem

Tags: stm32, stm32cubemx, hal-library, stm32l, truestudio

I am developing an application for a University project on my STM32L1DISCO board with the STM32L152RC MCU.

I have configured the pins and generated the init code via STM32CubeMX. I am using Atollic TrueSTUDIO as the IDE.

The problem is that the generated init code cannot run on my MCU. After spending a lot of time on debugging I found that the problem in the code is this one line using the HAL gpio library:

HAL_GPIO_Init(IDD_CNT_EN_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

Even though the preceding code is correct,

```
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */

 __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();

  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

__HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */

HAL_GPIO_WritePin(IDD_CNT_EN_GPIO_Port, IDD_CNT_EN_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : IDD_CNT_EN_Pin */

GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = IDD_CNT_EN_Pin;

GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;

GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;

GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
```

After stepping through the code line-by-line during debugging, I found that the HAL GPIO Init function does not execute and instead gives the runtime error: "Target not Responding, retrying...".

When I comment the HAL GPIO Init line, the program runs through with no issues.

STM32CubeMX includes the HAL library in the code. On top there is,

## include "stm32l1xx_hal.h"

So, I'm not sure what's causing the issue I'm seeing. I would really appreciate your help on this as I don't know what to try next.

Thank you.

Comment: You should step into the code of the init function and check deeper what can be wrong. What I also had one time, but was not related to GPIO pins directly, was that in STM32CubeMx, in Sys, Debug was not set to Serial Wire. This caused that suddenly debugging / connection lost came up during intialisation.

Comment: Hi Michel, thanks for the comment. I tried your suggestion and found the culprit to be this set of code within the HAL_GPIO_Init function:                                                 /* Configure IO Direction mode (Input, Output, Alternate or Analog) */
      temp = GPIOx->MODER;
      CLEAR_BIT(temp, GPIO_MODER_MODER0 << (position * 2));   
      SET_BIT(temp, (GPIO_Init->Mode & GPIO_MODE) << (position * 2));
      GPIOx->MODER = temp;                                                                  Any idea on why these lines of code may be problematic for the MCU?

Comment: No, sorry, I haven't dived in so much... are you sure you used the correct board/CPU type in CubeMx?  You also can try another GPIO pin (maybe there's a conflict somewhere).

Comment: Which pin is that IDD_CNT_EN_GPIO? PA13 or PA14 by any chance? This sounds like you are reconfiguring one of the SWD pins. Even hardfault would not cause this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

**`IDD_CNT_EN` is connected to the onboard power measurement circuitry. If not used properly, it will temporarily disrupt V<sub>DD</sub> power supply, resetting the MCU.**

Look at the schematics in the [User Manual](http://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00027954.pdf)

[image]

Setting `IDD_CNT_EN` to output low starts the external timer U3. After a delay of 150 ms, `Q13` of `U3` goes high, FET 1 in `U20` is switched off, and the **1kΩ shunt resistor `R22` is now connected in series with V<sub>DD</sub>** to improve the accuracy of the power measurement. The MCU should put itself to LOWPOWER, STOP or STANDBY mode, where consumption is well below 1 mA, within 150 ms of setting `IDD_CNT_EN` to low, and set it back to high in less than 150 ms after the wakeup signal on PA0 arrives.

Comment: Thanks berendi, Jan, and Michel. You all hit the problem on the nail: it was the IDD_CNT_EN pin conflict with being set as GPIO. Using another pin for GPIO works perfectly. Problem resolved. Thanks again!